# How to use Max and Min after filtered the row in pipe in R

Tags: r, filter, pipe, max, calculation

##### I want to understand what is weight-gap between max and min, use pipe option instead of assign the variables.

```
weightLogInfo_merged %>%
+ filter (Id == 6962181067 ) %>%
+ pull(WeightKg) %>% 
+ max(WeightKg) - min(WeightKg)
```

The error i get: Error in weightLogInfo_merged %>% filter(Id == 6962181067) %>% pull(WeightKg) %>%  : object 'WeightKg' not found

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `WeightKg` is a column of your dataset. Using `pull` will extract that column from your dataset as a vector but will not create a variable with this name in your enviroment. Instead pass the `pull`ed vector directly into the function you want to apply. However, as you want to apply two functions and compute the difference you have to wrap inside curly braces and use a `.` to specify where the result from the last step should be piped to.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl == 4) %>% 
  pull(mpg) %>%
  { max(.) - min(.) }
#> [1] 12.5
```

A second option to achieve the same result would be to use `range()` and `diff()` like so:

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl == 4) %>% 
  pull(mpg) %>%
  range() %>% 
  diff()
#> [1] 12.5
```

Comment: thanks all sorted

Answer (score 0):

Other options include `with`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl ==4) %>%
  with(., max(mpg) - min(mpg))
[1] 12.5
```

---

Or create the output within `summarise/reframe`

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl ==4) %>%
  summarise(diff = max(mpg) - min(mpg)) %>%
  pull(diff)
[1] 12.5
```

Or using the `magrittr` `%$%` operator

```
library(magrittr)
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl ==4) %$% 
 (max(mpg) - min(mpg))
[1] 12.5
```

Comment: Thanks all sorted